# How to link to the current URL + 1 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I'm looking to create a simple nav link that goes to the next or previous page in a series. The URL ends in a number and each successive page is just the next number in the sequence (.../101, /102, /103, etc). Is there a way to use javascript to link to the current URL + or - 1?

I know basically no javascript besides what I can copy and paste into HTML.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a good time to learn some JavaScript

Comment: `window+location.href =+ 1` should do the trick for you, as far as I understand your problem

Comment: Yash,  the next link is at the bottom of this page: https://www.pinnacledeals.net/101 Doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mark Okay, I anticipated that doing this your URL will be appended by 1, but I was wrong you'll have to append the whole number in, so let's say you're on 101 and wish to go to 102, so it would be `window.location.href =+ 102`

Comment: https://www.learn-js.org/

Comment: Is there a way to do it that could be applied to every page in the sequence without having to edit it to 102, 103, etc?

Comment: To all those saying I should learn JS, YES I agree but this project needs to be finished quicker than that.

Comment: `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\d+$/, '') + window.location.href.match(/\d+$/)[0] + 1`, `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\d+$/, '') + window.location.href.match(/\d+$/)[0] + 2`, +3.. etc

You can call these as onClick events of your links.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `location.href`, take `pathname`, split it and increment the last item with the value. Then join and assign to the pathname. Finally append the element to the body (or any other location).

Further readings:

- [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) all about `<a>`
- [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location) where you get the actuall href

```js
var url = document.createElement('a'),
    pathes;

url.href = 'http://example.com/123'; // or at the site: location.href
url.appendChild(document.createTextNode('link'));

pathes = url.pathname.split('/');
pathes[pathes.length - 1] = +pathes[pathes.length - 1] + 1;

url.pathname = pathes.join('/');

document.body.appendChild(url);
```